# making two fetch requests in one function with a delay in between

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

so I have 2 endpoints, I'm making a "post" request to the first one and in the response I should get some kind of id that I use in the second request endpoint url. so I want to make a delay or something till I get the response from the first request.

```
req = () => {
  fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {

    })
  fetch(`url with the id I get from the first request`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': bearer,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {

    })
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a delay? Promises are here for this kind of situation. In your last `.then` method of your first fetch, you can use the second fetch. Can't you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a delay per se. You can place your second request in the `.then` of the first request. This will ensure that your second request will run only once the first one has resolved. Another important note here, is that if you need a value of the first response in order to make the second request, you can only do that in the `.then` of the first request because otherwise the value you need to make the second request will be out of scope. Here is your code with the required modification.

```
req = () => {
  fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': bearer,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      fetch(`url with json.id or whatever`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': bearer,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion, if you return the inner fetch, you can not nest the .then chain. slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your second fetch request in your first request as:

```
req = () => {
  fetch("url", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: bearer,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    body:
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      fetch("url with the id I get from the first request", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: bearer,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {});
    });
};
```

Or you can use `async/await`.

```
req = async () => {
    const first = await ( await fetch( "url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: bearer,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body:
    } ) ).json();

    const second = await ( await fetch( `http://some.url${ first.id }` ),
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: bearer,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    } ).json();

    // use the variable second as your last result here.
  };
```